# UndeclaredThrowableException when calling an EJB method with Tomee 1.6

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, proxy, ejb, apache-tomee

I meet the following problem :

I have written an EJB which methods may throw a PersistanceException which is a checked exception (actually, it encapsulates a SQLException).
But when a client calls one of these methods and a PersistanceException is thrown, the client receives an UndeclaredThrowableException instead of the PersistanceException.

I have made some search on the web, and I understand that it happens when a client calls a dynamic proxy which was not designed to handle the checked exception that is actually thrown. But in my case, this dynamic proxy is automatically generated by the container (Tomme 1.6). So is it a bug of Tomee, or do I have missed something ?

Here is an illustration of the code :

### PersistanceException class : it is a checked exception

```
@ApplicationException( rollback=true)
public class PersistanceException extends Exception
{ 
    ...
}
```

### EJB interface

```
@Remote
public interface DbManager extends Serializable
{
    public Number runSequence( String datasourceName, String sequenceName) throws PersistanceException;

    ...
}
```

### EJB implementation

```
@Stateless
public class DbManagerBean implements fr.csf.srv.DbManager
{
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Number runSequence( String datasourceName, String sequenceName) throws PersistanceException
    {
        ...
        if( condition)
        {
            throw new PersistanceException( ...);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

### Client :

```
@Stateless
public class ...
{
    @EJB
    private DbManager dbManager;

    public void method()
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            dbManager.runSequence(...);
        }
        catch( PersistanceException e)
        {
            // The expected exception, but we never arrive here
        }
        catch( Throwable e)
        {
            // Unexpected exception. We get here, instead of the PersistanceException catch.
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Update ( 01 September 2014) :
I installed the last Tomee release (1.7.0) , but it doesn't change anything. The problem still remains. Here is the stacktrace. But it doesn't fit exactly with the example above, because I had to simplify it not to bother you with the business aspects of my application.

```
sept. 01, 2014 10:16:32 AM org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil handleSystemException
Grave: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: null
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy212.executePreparedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at fr.csf.refproduit.srv.RefProduitDbManagerBean.getProduitAdeFromPartenaireCanal(RefProduitDbManagerBean.java:359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:308)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:303)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:308)
    at $Proxy211.getProduitAdeFromPartenaireCanal(Unknown Source)
    at fr.csf.refproduit.ws.RefProduitService.getFormulesAssurance(RefProduitService.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:308)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:303)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:308)
    at fr.csf.refproduit.ws.RefProduitService$$LocalBeanProxy.getFormulesAssurance(fr/csf/refproduit/ws/RefProduitService.java)
    at fr.csf.refproduit.ws.RefProduit.getFormulesAssurance(RefProduit.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.performInvocation(EjbMethodInvoker.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.invoke(EjbMethodInvoker.java:76)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbInterceptor.intercept(EjbInterceptor.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:97)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invokeWebService(StatelessContainer.java:301)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:222)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.preEjbInvoke(EjbMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.invoke(EjbMethodInvoker.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.onMessage(CxfWsContainer.java:86)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsServlet.service(WsServlet.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: Table ou vue inexistante
```

Comment: I found a temporary workaround : I made the PersistanceException inherit from RuntimeException instead of Exception. I don't get the UndeclaredThrowableException anymore, but I am not satisfied because fondamentaly, this PersistanceException should be a checked exception.

Comment: UndeclaredThrowableException is probably a bug in the container, but showing the stack trace might show some detail that is being overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested my application with an other container (Glassfish 4.0), and it works perfectly well. So I can tell now that it is definitively a bug in Tomee 1.6.0, and unfortunately, this bug has not been corrected in the latest version 1.7.0.
It seems that MagicWand has found a patch, but I could not make it works. Is there a jar file to download and to put in Tomee lib directory ? or in the JVM classpath ?
Thank you for your help.
JMB.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of TomEE are you using, because this error looks like a container issue unrelated to your code. It seems that TomEE 1.6.0 had a bug, I have found a fix for class org.apache.openejb.util.classloader.ClassLoaderAwareHandler [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomee/tomee/trunk/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/util/classloader/ClassLoaderAwareHandler.java?r1=1588078&r2=1594292&diff_format=h). Might not be related to your case, but I suggest that you try to upgrade TomEE to at least 1.6.0.2 if you do not wont to break compatibility, or you can upgrade to the latest and greatest version 1.7.0 and see if it works.

Comment: Throwable is already Serializable, and if it weren't, UndeclaredThrowableException is unrelated to serialization.

Comment: @bkail you are right, my bad, Exception is always Serializable. It seems that some method on proxy object is throwing undeclared checked exception: http://tomee.apache.org/multiple-business-interface-hazzards.html

Comment: @jmb It seems that TomEE 1.6 had a bug, I have found a fix in org.apache.openejb.util.classloader.ClassLoaderAwareHandler: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomee/tomee/trunk/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/util/classloader/ClassLoaderAwareHandler.java?r1=1588078&r2=1594292&diff_format=h. Might not be related to your case, but I suggest that you try to upgrade TomEE to  at least 1.6.0.2 if you do not wont to break compatibility.

Comment: Yes, that looks very plausible, good find.  I recommend rewriting your answer to include that information instead.

Comment: @Magic Wand: I used Tomee 1.6.0.1. As you suggest, I installed the latest version of Tomee (1.7.0, ), but the problem remains. But perhaps the bug you found is not corrected yet ? I tried to implement the patch I found at your link, but it doesn't compile. What I understand eventually is that the problem seems to be in Tomee, and not in my code. So I will keep on trying each new version as soon as they are released, and hope that this bug will soon be corrected. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jmb as bkail suggested, your code is clean and there is nothing to it that looks like it causes this bug, so let's blame the container :-)